# Getting population by country using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, population

I was trying to get the population by country by using GEE. I tried the following code:

```
// world population 2015
var pop = ee.Image("JRC/GHSL/P2016/POP_GPW_GLOBE_V1/2015");
print(pop);
Map.addLayer(pop,{},'Population');

//world boundaries
var bound = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
print(bound);
Map.addLayer(bound,{},'boundaries');

// Getting Pop-2015 By country
var popcountry = pop.reduceRegions({
  collection:bound,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 250,
  });
print(popcountry);
Map.addLayer(popcountry,{},'PopC');
```

The issues that I see are the followings:

1. I only get a global population about 1 billions instead of about 7 bn.;
2. Many countries are zeros;
3. I tried to use different boundaries (specifically GADM), but I can't get any results as it appears something like `an internal error has ocurred`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'think' you should specifically set a crs in the `reduceRegions` function. As the calculation will run out of time (reprojection in different projection takes a lot of time), you should export the result to get a proper result.

```
// Getting Pop-2015 By country
var popcountry = pop.reduceRegions({
  collection:bound,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 250,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326', // world wide crs which seems to work for me
  });

Export.table.toAsset(popcountry.limit(10), 'worldPopTest', 'worldPopTest')
```

Note that I tried first setting the original crs (and crsTransform) as projection, but that did not work (I think due to this: [link forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/The$20CRS$20of$20a$20map$20projection$20could$20not$20be$20parsed/google-earth-engine-developers/YC4tezit37A/1EbuIn-_F_gJ), [link projections](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/operation/projection/TransverseMercator.html)). Therefore I choose the crs `EPSG:4326` and results seems to match the real populations.

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a32e785694f59f67b543ae8dbc542dd9)

Comment: Adding this specific crs ('EPSG:4326') overestimate the global population as the total population is reported to be 8.5 billion people instead of about 7.3 billion. Any other suggestions? Thanks.